# What is the process of building a world

Tags: aliens, worldbuilding-process

Is there a pattern that can be identified that we could use to build worlds? Is there something currently being used in certain circles?

Comment: I’m afraid your question is so broad, we can’t help you much. Worldbuilding is a subtype of writing, and just as there are many ways to write a book, there are many ways to build a world. Look online for worldbuilding examples; I might suggest the YouTube channels Nakari Speakerdane and Worldbuilding notes as a starting point.

Comment: Hi Thomas Blobaum, this is a great question for [our Meta site](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/) which exists to guide and resolve activities here in the main public site. Rules are pretty strict here, please review them at [HELP](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) - we have to maintain appearances and represent well to the public. Learning the ropes can be done by browsing around, or asking at the Meta. Thanks, hope to see your worlds soon!

Comment: Check the [description](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/worldbuilding-process/info) of the [tag:worldbuilding-process] tag. It has the explanation of a basic framework.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the kind of story you want to write, the kind of adventure you want to play.
2. Identify if this fits into an established genre. Learn the [conventions](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SingleBiomePlanet) of that genre, become aware of *prior art*.
3. Think of setting details which are *unique* to your own setting (or at least not used by well-known IP in the genre), and which enable the specific stories you want to tell.

For a classic sword-and-sorcery adventure, you can mix adventurers in plate armor, [shirtless barbarians](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ChainmailBikini) with big swords, and leather-clad rangers with bow, arrows, and slightly smaller swords. That's expected. You don't have to worry that [plate armor](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TwentyFourHourArmor) was historically for knights with an extensive support structure, squires and grooms and a fief to pay for all that. In a roleplaying game with halfway reasonable economics rules, because the players are expected to trade and buy, you need to worry about it -- unless there are [convenient](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/220544/this-dungeon-ruin-has-been-known-to-locals-for-ages-why-would-it-still-have-und) *dungeons* as a source of *loot* to fund the adventurers (never mind who re-stocks them and why).

In a [space opera](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StandardSciFiFleet) adventure, you can have single-seat starfighters running circles around lumbering battleships, because the mental image is World War II *in spaaaace!* For a more hard science fiction setting, you would note that delta-V tends to be at least as important as acceleration, and delta-V depends on mass ratios rather than absolutes. So the big battleship can actually outrun the fighter (which might still be able to turn faster).

You tagged this [aliens](/questions/tagged/aliens), so I presume it is a science-fiction world. The most important question is the degree of realism: Do you want 95% of the aliens to be humanoid, [able to drink, brawl](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BarFullOfAliens) and even [interbreed](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HalfHumanHybrid) with humans in a shirt-sleeve environment? Or are they [stranger](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StarfishAliens)? Completely absent?